# How to optimize this dynamic stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is retrieving data using 20 tables. 
Sample of the procedure:

```
     CREATE PROCEDURE GetEnquiries 
     (
        @EnquiryDate    DATETIME        = NULL
     )
     AS

     DECLARE @querySELECT           VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
     DECLARE @queryWHERE            VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
     DECLARE @queryExtraColumns     VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
     DECLARE @queryReturnResults    VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

     -----------------------------------------------------
     --Create temp table
     -----------------------------------------------------
     SET    @querySELECT = '
                CREATE  TABLE   #tempResults 
                (   
                    EnquiryId       INT, 
                    Cost            Decimal(18,2),
                    CustomerName    VARCHAR(50),
                    EnquiryStatus   VARCHAR(50),
                    ContactNumber   VARCHAR(50),
                    NumberOfVisits  INT 
                ) '

     -----------------------------------------------------
     --Insert into temp table
     -----------------------------------------------------  
     SET    @querySELECT = '            
                INSERT INTO #tempResults 
                (   
                    EnquiryId       , 
                    Cost            ,
                    CustomerName    ,
                    EnquiryStatus   ,
                    ContactNumber   
                ) '
     -----------------------------------------------------
     --SELECT
     -----------------------------------------------------
     SET    @querySELECT = '
            SELECT          
                    e.EnquiryId     , 
                    e.Cost          ,
                    c.CustomerName  ,
                    e.EnquiryStatus ,
                    c.ContactNumber 
            FROM    Enquiry e
                    INNER JOIN Customers c ON e.CustomerId = c.CustomerId '

     -----------------------------------------------------
     -- WHERE 
     -----------------------------------------------------
     IF(@EnquiryDate IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @queryWHERE = @queryWHERE + ' CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),e.EnquiryDate,23) >= '  + ''''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@EnquiryDate,23) + ''''
        END

     --- There are at least 14 parameters used in WHERE operation the above is just one of them
     -----------------------------------------------------
     -- Count NumberOfVisits
     -----------------------------------------------------
      SET   @queryExtraColumns = '
            ;WITH NumberOfVisits AS
            (
                SELECT  t.EnquiryId, COUNT(EnquiryId) AS NumberOfVisits 
                FROM    NumberOfVisits v 
                        INNER JOIN #tempResults t ON v.EnquiryId = t.EnquiryId
                GROUP   BY t.EnquiryId
            ) 


        UPDATE  #tempResults
        SET     NumberOfVisits = u.NumberOfVisits
        FROM    #tempResults t
                INNER JOIN NumberOfVisits u ON u.EnquiryId = t.EnquiryId

'

     -----------------------------------------------------
     -- return the results
     -----------------------------------------------------      
     SET    @queryReturnResults = '
            SELECT          
                    EnquiryId       , 
                    Cost            ,
                    CustomerName    ,
                    EnquiryStatus   ,
                    ContactNumber   ,
                    NumberOfVisits
            FROM    #tempResults t 
                     '

     -----------------------------------------------------
     -- Combine all the strings + DROP the temp table
     -----------------------------------------------------  
     -- PRINT(  @querySELECT + ' WHERE ' +  @queryWHERE + @queryExtraColumns +  @queryReturnResults + '  DROP TABLE #tempResults ') 
      EXEC( @querySELECT + ' WHERE ' +  @queryWHERE + @queryExtraColumns +  @queryReturnResults + '  DROP TABLE #tempResults ')
```

**Some facts:**

- The above procedure is the simple form of the Stored procedure i am working on.
- I am using SQL Server 2008
- My Actual procedure has 15 parameters, all of them are used in WHERE clause. If the value is provided for a parameter, the parameter is included in the WHERE clause otherwise not.
- There are at least 10 columns whos value comes from the GROUP BY condition like the one "NumberOfVisits" given in the above procedure.
- I have indexes on all the Primary Keys & Foreign Keys.
- I have indexes on all the columns that are used in the WHERE clause.
- I have indexes on all the columns that are used in the GROUP BY clause.

**Questions**:

- Q1: Is this is according to the best practice to create dynamic stored procedures following above pattern?
- Q2: I got the output SQL of this procedure by using:
  -- PRINT(   @querySELECT + ' WHERE ' +  @queryWHERE + @queryExtraColumns +  @queryReturnResults + '  DROP TABLE #tempResults ') 
  when i run that SQL it took the same time that was taken by the stored procedure, why? isn't the SQL should take less time? why there is no difference?
- Q3:  Is the above is the best practice to get the value of summary columns("NumberOfVisits") ?
- Q4: is the above is the best way to create the WHERE clause dynamically?
- Q5: Can i avoid the use of Temporary table by using some alternate in the above scenario?
- Q6: What can i do to optimize this procedure?

Please forgive me, if my question is NOT clear or not a proper question.

Thanks for your valuable time & help.

Comment: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same question was also posted on another site by me. This question was answered by [Grant Fritchey](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/users/34/grant-fritchey/)
You can see the answer [here](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/81444/how-to-optimize-this-dynamic-stored-procedure/81448)
I have copied the answer from that site, see below:

> In general, instead of building a string and executing it, which can
>   be subject to SQL injection attacks, I'd suggest building a string
>   with parameters and using sp_executesql to execute it, providing the
>   parameters. It's more work, but it's more secure, AND, it's more
>   likely to see improved plan reuse.
>
> No, the query is the long part of the execution. Building a few
>   strings is pretty pain free.
>
> In terms of summary columns, no, that's an extra pass. Instead I'd
>   perform a join against a sub-select (usually, sometimes breaking it
>   down into steps can work better).
>
> Nope. See above. sp_executesql is better.
>
> Yeah, plan it out as a single select statement. The temp table is just
>   holding for the aggregation which can be done as a derived table.
>
> Optimize? Tougher question. Just seeing what you have, the CONVERT
>   statement on e.EnquiryDate is going to cause a scan, no matter what.
>   If that's a datetime column, you need to compare that to a datetime
>   value, no conversions. Beyond that, I couldn't say without seeing the
>   whole queries, execution plans, data, structure, all that.
>
> In general, these catch all type queries are extremely problematic.
>   Instead of doing this, identify the common patterns that will
>   inevitably exist, these three columns always come in, this one only
>   comes in when another one comes in, etc., and then build three or four
>   different procs that take take into account these patterns and use
>   this as a wrapper proc to determine which of those procs it should go
>   to. It'll be work to set up, but no more than this, and it will
>   perform better and will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic reporting, you are better off setting up SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services), which is a part of SQL Server 2005 through 2008 R2. Then use BIDS to create a data model project to run Report Builder against. Report Builder comes with SSRS and is a click-once application.

In this day and age, trying to keep up with dynamic reporting via home-grown queries just isn't as efficient anymore.